# Angular 5 form validation (required) not working

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, angular-forms

I am learning Angular 5 with TypeScript. I am completely new to it. I am now trying to construct a form and validating it. But it is not working properly.

This is my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
    animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    loginForm: FormGroup;

    errors = [];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public router: Router, private globals: GlobalsService, private http: Http) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
            password: new FormControl("")
        });
    }

    onLoggedin(formData) {
        
        alert("Submit form");
  
  
    }

}
```

As you can see I am setting "required" validation attribute on the email field.
This is my html.

```
<div class="login-page" [@routerTransition]>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="150px" class="user-avatar" />
            <h1>Yo Cash Flow</h1>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngFor="let error of errors">
                <strong>{{ error.msg }}</strong>
            </div>
            <form [formGroup]="loginForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onLoggedin(loginForm.value)">
                <div class="form-content">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" placeholder="Email">
                        <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors.required" class="text-danger">Email is required</div>
                    </div>

 
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-btn"> Log in </button>
                &nbsp;
                <a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Sign up</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am trying to show the error individually. I mean for "required" attribute, I am retrieving the error message like this errors.required. But it is not working. But when I tried to use "valid" like below, it is working.

```
loginForm.controls['email'].invalid
```

But I want to retrieve the error individually because I want to show the different message for the different error. How can I fix this? Why it is not working when I use `loginForm.controls["email"].errors.required`? What is the correct way of showing the different message for the different validation rule?

Comment: Do you know why your original code did not work? It looks to me like you were using the correct syntax. Did you only need to add the elvis operator: `*ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors?.required"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `errors` property, like so:

```
loginForm.controls['email'].errors
```

If there are no errors, it will return null, otherwise it will return an object like so:

```
{ required : true }
```

Then you simply need to create a function that will return a human readable error message, like so:

```
getErrorMessage(controlName, displayName) {
    let result = "";
    let errors  = loginForm.controls[controlName].errors;
    if (errors.required) {
        result += (displayName + " is required.");
    }
    if (errors.whatever) {
        result += "Whatever you like";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. But can I show the different error message for the different rule? I mean, for "required", I would like to show "email is required". Then maybe I will have another rule to check format and show "invalid email format". I think I cannot do it just by only using loginForm.controls['email'].errors.

Comment: You just need to create a function to build your human readable error messages. I've updated my answer to give a basic example of what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent a couple of hours trying to debug this problem in my project, the problem in my case turned out to be using:

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="testing" />
```

instead of:

```
<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="form.controls['testing']" />
```

In my case the FormControl "testing" is dynamically added using form.AddControl() - the second way of performing the name binding also binds the model to the input.

Hoping this can help someone with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You must use `(loginForm.valid)` inside the `*ngIf` or [disabled] property of the button. This automatically checks whether the form is validated or not from the ts file.

Moreover, inside the ts file, you can write your validations:

```
new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular docs exists two ways to validate forms, try to use the "correct" way for your expected result:

- [Template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#building-a-template-driven-form) - works better in simple forms (static validators)
- [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) - works better when you need transform validators dynamically (more complex forms)

I suggest learning Reactive Forms (Template-driven gets easier after learning it).

In Reactive Forms:

- HTML:

```
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLoggedin(loginForm.value)">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors?.required && email.touched">Email is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern && email.touched">Invalid Pattern</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit"[disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

- TS

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      loginForm: FormGroup;
    
      errors = [];
    
      email: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$'),
      ]);
      password: FormControl = new FormControl('');
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
      }
    
      onLoggedin(formData) {
        alert('Submit form');
      }
```

Notes:

- I declare FormControls at root of component to directly bind in html file;
- In validator messages "email.errors?.required" I use ? to allow "email.errors"(when email is valid) be null and not throw error;.