# Angular 5 material: dropdown (select) required validation is not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I have a material dropdown inside my ngForm, when I set this select as required it shows an asterisk * beside it but the form is seen as valid if I don't select any option from the dropdown.

```
<mat-form-field class="col-4 offset-1">
<mat-select placeholder="Some placeholder" [(value)]="data.name" required>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name.value">
    name.viewValue
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is unlike what happens if I set the material input to required which will make the form invalid if it is empty.

```
<mat-form-field class="col-4 offset-1">
 <input matInput name="dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth" [(ngModel)]="data.dob" required>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I prefer to solve this using a template driven approach not by using ReactiveForms ( I found some solution talking about the ReactiveForms), can anyone help me?

Note:

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037287/angular-5-form-validation-required-not-working) of similar title but it is using FormGroup (reactiveForms)

I have put an example to give an idea in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbc3ts?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You added `required` to the select's `option`, not the `select`. Do it like:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" name="select" [(ngModel)]="select" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" >
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-99msgq?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: sorry bro, I mistakenly did this initially in the stackblitz but updated it just after putting the question , in both places it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Have you checked my link? There form is invalid if not selected in mat-select

Comment: Yes, I see it worked with you, let me try it in my code , will update you shortly (strangely I almost used the same code like you except the name attr maybe ?)

Comment: Yes and `[(NgModel)]`. `name` attribute is used by Angular to assign a formControl so it is mandatory to have

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't have , now it is working !! thanks mate !
 I truly appreciate your help

Comment: Above answer working fine on mandatory validation. But when I submit info with valid info it can not work as there is no attribute to bind selected id. Existing code where selected element id is bind to ng model.<select name="type" required [(ngModel)]='selectedelement.id'>
   <option *ngFor="let obj of elements" [value]="obj.id">
   {{obj.description}}
   </option>
</select> \n But if I changed to above solution it looks as follows, <select name="type" required [(ngModel)]='type'>
   <option *ngFor="let obj of elements" [value]="obj.id">
   {{obj.description}}
   </option>
</select>

Answer (score 8):

Based on the excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087625/7588447) of (from zero to hero), I want to clarify 2 points mentioned in comments:

1- You have to use **ngModel** not **value**

2- You have to give the control a name

Full credit goes to him, I wanted to clarify this to any newcomer like me as it took me 2 hours to find out why it doesn't work

Comment: Both ngModel and value should work according to the Material documentation.

Comment: Want to add a 3rd point - check the ngModel value, In my case, the Default value was 0 and there were not single options in the list having the 0 option value and that's why form showing green